# Why do I have a redswoosh-install.log in my /tmp?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, security, malware

My /tmp directory contains a file called redswoosh-install.log.

Wikipedia tells me that RedSwoosh was a peer-to-peer content delivery company, later acquired by Akamai.

The file was created yesterday, I do not recall having installed anything that day, or running anything unusual.

Is there some legitimate Mac software (or browser plugin) that includes RedSwoosh, or should I be worried?

Comment: Do you use Photoshop ? http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=908665

Comment: @Sathya: Interesting. No Photoshop, but some other Adobe tools. And of course Flash player.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by Sathya, I found that I have /Applications/Akamai, which was put there by an Adobe installer.

This is not malware, and there is proper documentation and even management tools in the folder:

> The Akamai NetSession Interface runs as a service to manage downloads and to
>   let you manage the download process. It was installed on your computer when you
>   downloaded content that uses the service to provide secure, high integrity
>   downloads of large files.
>
> The NetSession Interface supports downloading from a central source and between
>   peers. When peer-downloading is enabled, your computer can serve as an upload
>   source for other computers -- without adverse impacts to your computing.
>   Peer-to-peer downloading can provide faster, more effective downloads.
>
> The NetSession Interface contains no adware or spyware, is safe and secure,
>   uses minimal resources, and provides you the ability to manage and control its
>   actions, including the ability to uninstall it if you do not want it on your
>   computer.

I am going to uninstall it anyway.

Comment: If it worked, remember to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer. You should do this on all your questions, if they have working answers

Comment: @SimonSheehan: I am very hesitant to accept my own answers...

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable, feel free. You should go through your questions and make sure you've accepted answers if a solution worked